# Flask: request method not picking up the datetime value from web form via AJAX

Tags: ajax, datetime, flask

I am creating a web form where one two fields are of `datetime` data types. Then I am passing this form data to server via AJAX. Below is the code JQuery snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
var start = $("#start").val();
var end = $("#end").val();
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/interuption',

        data: $('#formint').serializeArray(),
        success: function(response){
                alert(response);
                },
        error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
    });

});
});
```

Associated HTML is as follows:

```
<form id = "formint" class="myForm" method= "post" action="/interuption">
<th>
<label>Start Time Stamp
<input id = "start" type="datetime-local" name="start_timestamp" required>
</label>
</th>

<th>
<label>End Time Stamp
<input id ="end" type="datetime-local" name="end_timestamp" required>
</label>
</th>
</form>
```

On the server side I am using Flask. I am using `request.form.get` methods to retrieve the `datetime`. Then I am trying to push this to MS SQL Server. Below is the Python code snippets.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(#credentials)
cursor=cnxn.cursor()
query_insert = "INSERT INTO test.dbo.testFeed(start_timestamp,end_timestamp) 
VALUES (?,?)"

@app.route('/interuption',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def interuption():
    try:
        data_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form.get('start'),%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
        data_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.form.get('end'),%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')
        if data_1 and data_2:
            cursor.execute(query_insert,(data_1,data_2))
            cnxn.commit()
            cnxn.close()
            return json.dumps({'status':'OK'})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'error':'data has not been insterted!!'})
     except Exception as e:
         return json.dumps({'excp':str(e)})
    return render_template('form.html')
```

When I am running the above codes, I am getting an error as follows

`{"excp": "time data 'None' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'"}`

Clearly that `request.form.get` is not picking up any value from the web form.

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

When sending form data as key-value pairs to the server, the key will be the `name` attr of the `<input>` (not `id`), so you should try `request.form.get('start_timestamp')` and `request.form.get('end_timestamp')` instead.

Comment: Thanks Grey. I have another doubt, what is the difference between `request.form['field']` and `request.form.get['field']`

Comment: It's almost like what you do with `dict`. If you pass a non-exist key, `dict['badkey']` will throw out a `KeyError` exception (In Flask, it will be a 400 Bad Request response), but `dict.get('badkey')` will return `None` instead. Besides, you can set a default value with `get()` (e.g. `dict.get('key', 'default value')`).